# Trying to reformat a Lenovo t410 with ubuntu installed already?

Tags: boot, 13.04, 13.10, lenovo, usb-installation

I had an old Thinkpad t410, and let my brother use it for a while. He stopped using it and forgot the password (User or personal account password). It currently has 13.04 or 13.10, and i have a USB formatted with unetbootin. Ive tried going through both the BIOS menu and the f12 menu, but am having issues. How can i reformat the drive so its just a fresh install?

Edit: Turns out i didnt have the right thing in the BIOS startup line up. I figured it out, and switched it in. Its now installing.

Comment: Password to what?  Is it a HDD password?  or a user password on Ubuntu 13.x (which shouldn't be a problem).  (I've assumed its not BIOS due to bios menu mention)

Comment: Its his user password.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ubuntu install media as a 'live' system, boot it and use "try ubuntu"

- `mount` the hdd to check for any wanted files  [optional]
- use `gparted` to reformat the drive and erase any data  [optional]

Neither step is mandatory. You can select the 'format partition' checkbox   under 'something else' for a new install.  Key is not to upgrade, just select 'Something Else' as your install option, and you have control to alter partitions, format, or  use existing...

You can overwrite the password with a known one (hashed) if you know the encryption used (its usually default), but its cleaner just to start again as you intended.

Comment: I know how to install it, once the drive shows up in the bios, i just need help getting the drive to show up in the BIOS.

Comment: when you power up - do you see a strange symbol, a sort of lock? with cursor waiting for password (ie. hdd password?)  or are you using Ubuntu 17.10  (be specific - ie. Ubuntu 17.10.1 is not Ubuntu 17.10)

Comment: It could also be the drive is faulty/iffy -- whilst using 'try ubuntu' install & run `smartctl` to check the health/status of your drive (`smartmontools ` is the package from memory you may need to grab on install media to use `smartctl`)

Comment: There are no system passwords, for the BIOS, just the user password inside the already installed Ubuntu, which im trying to clean install over.

Comment: And im trying to get to the Try ubuntu point, but the USB im using is mounting until after the OS is loaded, not in the BIOS where i need it.